# EventListener for Dropdown list generated through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can't seem to latch an eventlistener to a dropdown that is being generated through Javascript.

Html that is generated:

```
<select class="specialConditionsDropdown">
    <option value="-1" selected>Some Value</option>
</select>
```

Javascript I have ended up on:

```
$(document).on("change", ".specialConditionsDropdown", function () {
console.log("I changed");
}, false);
```

I noticed that any html generated through javascript would not work with .change() so I have had to use the .on() to do the same. I am not sure why this won't pick up on a change within the dropdown as it works on everything else I have used it with.

Also the drop down gets populated through javascript:

```
function PopulateSpecialConditionTables()
{
    $('.specialConditionsDetails').empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < SpecialConditions.length; i++)
    {
        if(SpecialConditions[i].Value != "None")
        {
            var specialConditionsTable = $(document.createElement('tr'));
            specialConditionsTable.wrapInner().html('<td style="width: 10px"><input       class="specialConditionCheckBox" type="checkbox" /></td>' +
                '<td class="specialConditionValue">' + SpecialConditions[i].Value + '</td><td class="specialConditionDescription">' + SpecialConditions[i].Description + '</td>');
            $('.specialConditionsDetails').append(specialConditionsTable);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full function for populating the table that contains the dropdown:

```
function PopulateDemographicTables(demographics)
{
$('.demographicDetails').empty();

for (var i = 0; i < demographics.length; i++)
{
    var demogrphicsTable = $(document.createElement('tr'));

    if (demographics[i].Name == "Special Conditions")
    {
        demogrphicsTable.wrapInner().html('<td style="width: 10px"><input class="demographicCheckBox" type="checkbox" /></td><td class="demographicName">' +
                demographics[i].Name + '</td><td class="demographicValue" spellcheck="false"><select class="specialConditionsDropdown">' +
                '<option value="-1" selected>' + demographics[i].Value + '</option></select></td>');
        SelectedSpecialCondition = demographics[i].Value
    }
    else
    {
        demogrphicsTable.wrapInner().html('<td style="width: 10px"><input class="demographicCheckBox" type="checkbox" /></td><td class="demographicName">' +
            demographics[i].Name + '</td><td class="demographicValue" spellcheck="false" contenteditable>' + demographics[i].Value + '</td>');
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < DefaultDemographics.length; j++)
    {
        if (demographics[i].Name == DefaultDemographics[j].Name && demographics[i].Value == DefaultDemographics[j].Value)
        {
            demogrphicsTable.find('.demographicCheckBox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            demogrphicsTable.addClass("defaulted");
        }
    }

    $('.demographicDetails').append(demogrphicsTable);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
$(document).on("change", ".specialConditionsDropdown", function () {
   console.log("I changed");
}); //Removed false from here
```

*Correct syntax* is

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )

For more info visit [**.on()**](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Well that did it, I completely forget why I even have the false their.